Request timeout in magento site
top - 13:10:35 up  8:37,  1 user,  load average: 14.94, 14.73, 14.82
Tasks: 290 total,  15 running, 274 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 93.6%us,  5.2%sy,  0.6%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.5%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65929760k total, 36148480k used, 29781280k free,  3908064k buffers
Swap: 33038332k total,        0k used, 33038332k free,  5137772k cached
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
30431 barriers  20   0  648m 195m  40m R 76.4  0.3  18:07.72 lsphp
4364 barriers  20   0  646m 262m  34m R 74.4  0.4   1:40.73 lsphp
3679 barriers  20   0  758m 212m  39m R 72.4  0.3   3:43.98 lsphp
3753 barriers  20   0  528m 146m  34m R 70.1  0.2   3:32.59 lsphp
4385 barriers  20   0  626m 173m  39m R 69.1  0.3   1:31.93 lsphp
32685 barriers  20   0  734m 185m  39m R 67.1  0.3  12:33.42 lsphp
4182 barriers  20   0  595m 213m  34m R 66.1  0.3   2:25.68 lsphp
5146 barriers  20   0  589m 205m  32m R 60.4  0.3   0:15.57 lsphp
32328 barriers  20   0  797m 252m  42m R 60.1  0.4  13:05.09 lsphp
2821 mysql     20   0 17.2g  13g 9632 S 51.8 21.9 210:09.10 mysqld
5220 barriers  20   0  503m 112m  25m R 23.6  0.2   0:00.71 lsphp
5221 barriers  20   0  517m 123m  24m R 16.9  0.2   0:00.51 lsphp
5222 barriers  20   0  477m  68m 9.9m R  5.0  0.1   0:00.15 lsphp
7792 root      39  19 1368m 1.2g 3576 R  2.7  1.9   3:07.28 clamscan
5046 barriers  38  18 1570m 100m 6780 S  2.0  0.2   0:00.47 ecomscan
4731 nobody    20   0  199m  48m 7368 R  1.3  0.1   8:45.24 litespeed
These are my proccesses runninng getting connection timeout while exporting data by using magento admin panel.
We have 10.000 monthly users approx so small website
please help me to relove this issue.
I have tried increase php memory execution time and memory limit

Additional DB information request, please.
OS, Version?
cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Try noabort and see if it helps. https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lsws/extapp/php/configuration/control/#htaccess
